# Duplicate records found in Advanced Pricing Export Report in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, importexport, advanced-pricing

I am using magento 2.3.0, while exporting Advance Pricing report, I am getting duplicates for some of the rows.. There are no duplicates in the table.All looks fine.

I am not able to figure out the reason for this duplication issue. Is there any system error reported regarding this??